# MySQL INSERT and UPDATE queries not working on PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm working on a website with PHP and MySQL, first I use XAMPP to preview the building of my site, everything is working fine here (XAMPP PHP version is 5.7), the problem is when I uploaded through FTP the content of my site, the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries aren't working on my PHP scripts.

I've read some articles about the compatibility issues between both versions, FTP server is using PHP 5.2.17.

The `SELECT` queries are working fine in the server, so, login into database is not the issue.

This is my code using `UPDATE`:

```
include_once 'db_post.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATA_HOST, DATA_USER, DATA_PASSWORD, DATA_DATABASE);

$catTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['catName']);
$catDesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['catDesc']);
$catID = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['ID']); // I get this in the redirection, the value isn't in the POST form

$cT = "UPDATE categorias SET NombreCat = '$catTitle', DescripcionCat = '$catDesc', ImagenCat = 'no_image.png' WHERE IDCat = $catID"; 

if ($mysqli->query($cT) === TRUE) { header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&Edit=Successful"); }
else { header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&Edit=Error"); }
```

The redirection goes through the error and nothing is saved in the database.

Another info about my DB is that I'm using InnoDB instead of MyISAM, which allegedly is recommended in phpMyAdmin.

Also when I'm trying to insert a row, there's no query:

```
include_once 'db_post.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATA_HOST, DATA_USER, DATA_PASSWORD, DATA_DATABASE);

$catTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['catName']);
$catDesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['catDesc']);

$cT = "INSERT INTO categorias (IDCat, NombreCat, DescripcionCat, ImagenCat) VALUES (null, '$catTitle', '$catDesc', 'no_image.png')"; 

if ($mysqli->query($cT) === TRUE) { header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&Add=Successful"); }
else { header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&Add=Error"); }
```

So the question is, **which is the correct form to query in MySQL in that version of PHP?**

Comment: So what error does MySQL give you as a reason for it not succeeding?

Comment: Why are you using a 10 year old version of PHP? That's just begging for your site to be hacked. That, and inserting user data into your database without checking it...

Comment: @miken32 the hosting server owners don't want to update their PHP, I can't do it from my house. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection hacks, and you should also be capturing error messages. PDO makes this much easier than mysqli:

```
include_once 'db_post.php';
$dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", DATA_HOST, DATA_DATABASE);
$db = new PDO($dsn, DATA_USER, DATA_PASSWORD);

if (empty($_GET["ID"])) {
    $action = "Add";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO categorias (IDCat, NombreCat, DescripcionCat, ImagenCat) VALUES (null, ?, ?, 'no_image.png')";
    $result = $db->prepare([$_POST["catName"], $_POST["catDesc"]);
} else {
    $action = "Edit";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE categorias SET NombreCat = ?, DescripcionCat = ?, ImagenCat = 'no_image.png' WHERE IDCat = ?";
    $result = $stmt->execute([$_POST["catName"], $_POST["catDesc"], $_GET["ID"]]);
}

if ($result === true) {
    header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&$action=Successful");
} else {
    error_log("Database error: " . $stmt->errorInfo());
    header("Location: ../management.php?Action=ManageCategories&$action=Error");
}
```

Now, if you have an error, just check your logs.

Comment: The method about safe queries using PDO was useful, after checking my code I've found the problem was in the SQL statement, my table name is, for example "Categories" and in my code is "categories", the problem was the upper C that worked OK in XAMPP but not in the server.